# sharing mouse click and key press events through windows (or handles)

Tags: c#, macros, transparent, handle

I have 3, and sometimes more duplicates of an executable, and what I would like to do is to reduce workforce by sharing mouse click and key press events through all applications, with C#.

I am able to get handle's of executables, so ideas might be based on acquired handles.

Also I have done some work to ease my work, all applications are arranged at same coordinates, with the same window size. So basically transparent mouse and key clicks which will interact with all windows (the top window, as well as background windows) would do the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to sned Windows Messages from one application to the other, but that involves security configuration.

Here you have how to do it:

[Communication between applications via Windows Messages](http://ryanfarley.com/blog/archive/2004/05/10/605.aspx)

Here you have comments about security issues, and ideas for alternative solutions

[Sending, receiving and processing a windows message between windows applications](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winforms/thread/6a7915f1-42a4-4f82-a2c6-9c149c99d7f1)

Answer (score 0):

Stacking the windows isn't necessary.  Once you have the handle to all the windows that you want to interact with, P/Invoke the SendMessage API to send your click to each window at it's target coordinates.

If I had the need for such a thing, I would put a picture box on a form and capture the image of one of the windows (so I can see what I'm clicking), then process the PictureBox.Click event to calculate the coordinates to use in the P/Invoke call(s).

There are several other tricks you could use to make your life easier and click-sharing utility better, but this will get you started.

Comment: so far I have used handles to call their windows front, could you give a brief example on sendmessage api for sending clicks. Plus, I should be using one of the duplicate windows in order to keep working. Are you suggesting to use a transparent picturebox ? Else, i misunderstood you.

Comment: @Bartu SendMessage: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.sendmessage, I'm just suggesting that your C# application has it's own form, with a picutre of the window(s) that you want to interact with.  Since they are all the same application you just need one of them to give you some visual reference while clicking.  Your needs may vary.